# How to process CSV and return to front end using cloud functions?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to use cloud functions and Firebase storage to achieve the following:

1. User uploads CSV to front end.
2. I save that CSV to Firebase storage
3. A cloud function is triggered
4. The cloud function does some processing on the CSV and creates a new CSV
5. The new CSV is saved to Firebase storage and a response is sent to the front end detailing where to read the new csv

How can I go about achieving this using cloud functions?
Instead of triggering the function using cloud storage, should I make the function get triggered via a HTTP request?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The process to handle this is the following:

1. First upload the CSV to a user upload directory from the client as a data blob/file
2. On complete, invoke a Cloud Function OnCall with the reference path to the blob/file
3. Cloud function loads the Storage item, and checks it as a CSV, decodes it based on any specific parameters either hardcoded or provided.
4. Save the new CSV to a new storage path or overwrite it and either:
5. Generate a download URL and hand it to the client, OR
6. Pass the CSV content directly to the client as the response (size limitations apply)

You could do this with `onRequest`, but it would be ideal to use `onCall` for context from the client. Additionally, Firebase-Storage and Node are not supported on storage but rather depend on `Google-Cloud-Storage` modules, link in sources along with two highly recommended CSV parsers for Node/js environments.

Source:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#upload_from_a_blob_or_file
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#call_the_function
- https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-parse
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv

Comment: Why a blob? You can easily store .csv, .tab or really any kind of file in storage. Manipulating the .csv file directly takes several steps and code out of this process. Just curious...

Comment: Consistency, primarily. Data blobs are easier to handle from unknown data types from a user and converting to a data stream and back is 1 line of code.

Comment: I see. Thanks for that. Since the OP specifically states that the files are .csv, that step (casting to blob) may be unneeded but good answer either way! Upvote for you!

Comment: How would you handle a .csv where you know what kind of columns there are (for instance name, age, weight), but not in which order and how exactly they are written? (lastname instead of name for example) The user would need to somehow state that lastname refers to "name" and the function should then place all lastname values of that .csv into "name" on the database. Is that possible?

Comment: Objects in javascript don't respect the order of properties. its normally implied through allocation in memory. as for printing it in order, Lodash is a data coders dream, you can parse your csv into a json object and detect its values and output them in the order you prefer. its mostly semantics and decoration at that point.

if your question is related to the data itself, then the csv is most likely corrupted. you would have to detect types they are cast to, but that gets down to a specific set of data to debug and can't be a 'general answer' - for this, please make a dedicated question